# Appropriate use of Grails, Rails, etc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grails, groovy, agile

We've got an Excel spreadsheet floating around right now (globally) at my company to capture various pieces of information about each countries technology usage. The problem is that it goes out, gets changes, but they're never obvious, and often conflicting - and then we have to smash them together. To me, the workbook is no more than a garbage in/garbage out type application waiting to be written.

In a company that has enough staff and knowledge to dedicate to Enterprise projects, for some reason, agile and language/frameworks such as Rails, Grails, etc. are frowned upon. That said, I can't help but think that this is almost a perfect fit for the need, given the scaffolding features for extremely simple implementations of capturing raw fields with only a couple lookups (i.e. a pre-defined category). I'm thinking this would be considered a very appropriate use of these frameworks.

Has anyone worked on these types of quick and dirty apps before in normally large-scale, heavy-handed enterprise environments with success? Any tips for communicating this need/appropriateness to non-technical management?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to get this implemented in a rigid organization is to get this working and demo it -- without approval. It's very hard for management to say no to a finished project.

Answer (score 3):

I work for a really big company & have written many utility apps based on Rails (as well as contributed to some larger Rails projects).  That said, the biggest concern is not the quality of the app, but who's going to support/maintain it when you leave or get hit by the bus.

IMHO, The major fear that an enterprise organization has - especially if the application becomes more critical to it's core business - is how to support it.  If it doesn't fit into it's neat little box of supported technologies, it's less likely to happen.

Corporations have been bitten by this many times in the past & are cautious when bringing in new technology.

So, if you can drum up more folks to learn Ruby/Rails in your group (or elsewhere in your company), you may be able to make a good case for it.  Otherwise, sad to say, your probably better off implementing something on Sharepoint :-(.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a Java infrastructure, then creating a Grails app will require little to no additional IT ramp up to support and maintain. The support and maintenance cost and effort should be the same as for a Java application (i.e. Grails apps run on Tomcat, use the same JVM, use the same diagnostic/profiling tools, etc.).

In my experience, larger IT organizations have a harder time supporting Ruby when its not already in the toolchain because its a new language, new deployment environment, and requires a considerable amount of support and maintenance ramp up.

I would develop a minimal viable product, then make friends with someone in IT who can help you deploy it into a staging or production environment. Then get a few of the users to hop on board and test it like its a Beta product. After that, open it up to a larger audience.

So as others have said, forgiveness over permission, but be smart about the impact on the IT organization.